# How to count object values using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object with arrays inside. This arrays are grouped by the 'sku'.
And now i should count the object values inside the grouped sku's. So if there is a farbigkeit, proof or eindruck count them how often do they apear and also sum the quan.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tokadmwn/2/

```
    <pre id="result"></pre>
```

javascript:

```
var myData = [
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 100, farbigkeit: "A90ZUKOs4599", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs18dp", quan: 100 },
    { sku: "9017WAs18dp", quan: 50, eindruck: "A90ZUKOs4799" },
    { sku: "9017WAs18dp", quan: 40, eindruck: "A90ZUKOs4799", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 200, farbigkeit:"A90ZUKOs4699", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 200, farbigkeit:"A90ZUKOs4599" }
];

function groupBy(propertyName, array) {
    var groupedElements = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var element = array[i];             
        var value = element[propertyName];
        var quantity = element['quan'];

        var group = groupedElements[value];
        if(group == undefined) {
            group = [element];
            groupedElements[value] = group;
        } else {
            group.push(element);
        }
    }
    return groupedElements;
}

var result = groupBy("sku", myData);
console.log(result);
$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: Why are you showing `groupBy`?

Comment: a new object with couted values gruped by sku

Comment: What is input, groupedElements or myData?

Comment: The input is myData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
function aggr(data) {
    var res={};
    myData.forEach(function(item){
        res[item.sku]=res[item.sku]||{quan:0};
        res[item.sku].quan+=1*item.quan;
        ["farbigkeit","proof","eindruck"].forEach(function(p) {
            res[item.sku][p]=(res[item.sku][p]?res[item.sku][p]:0)+(item[p]?1:0);
        })
    });
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myData = [
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 100, farbigkeit: "A90ZUKOs4599", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs18dp", quan: 100 },
    { sku: "9017WAs18dp", quan: 50, eindruck: "A90ZUKOs4799" },
    { sku: "9017WAs18dp", quan: 40, eindruck: "A90ZUKOs4799", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 200, farbigkeit:"A90ZUKOs4699", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 200, farbigkeit:"A90ZUKOs4599" }
];

var groupedData = myData.reduce(function(result, current) {
    result[current.sku] = result[current.sku] || [];
    result[current.sku].push(current);
    return result;
}, {});

for (var key in groupedData){
    groupedData[key] = groupedData[key].length;
}

console.log(groupedData);
```